# 〜くれて, what is the meaning and how do people use it?

Tags: て-form

Just like the title suggest, I once in a while will encounter なになにてくれて。what does it really mean and how normally people use it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

「くれて」 is the te-form of the verb 「くれる」.

「くれる」 can be used by itself to mean "to give" or "to let one have" as in

> 「ケンちゃんがあめをくれた。」 = "Ken-chan gave me candies."

The other usage of 「くれる」, which is what you are clearly referring to, is to express that you, the speaker, are the receiver of an action by another person.  For this, 「くれる」 needs to be attached to another verb to form a "Verb + て + くれる"

> 「ヘレンさんはいつも（ボクに）英語{えいご}を教{おし}えてくれる。」 = "Helen always teaches me English."
>
> 「お[母]{かあ}さんがクッキーを[焼]{や}いてくれた。」 = "Mom baked cookies for me."

Finally, the continuative form of that is "Verb + て + くれて" and here is how it is used.  You need to use the 「て」 **twice**.

> 「[来]{き}**て**くれ**て**ありがとう。」 = "Thanks for coming!"
>
> 「[君]{きみ}がここにい**て**くれ**て**[嬉]{うれ}しい。」 = "I am happy that you are here (for me)."